# como usar line-through dentro de um item do array

Tags: javascript, html

estou criando uma lista de tarefas e estou tendo dificuldade para mostrar ela como concluída. O único ítem de array que é riscado com a função  line-through é o ultimo e meu objetivo é que todos possam ser marcados conforme seja necessário.
exemplo: 4 entrada e quero marca palavra ceneta e palavra caderno .

agenda
**caneta**
**caderno**
Borracha

mas dificuldade que estou tendo e que clico pra marca caderno ele só esta dando efeito da marca na ultima opção no caso exemplo borracha

```js
const ul = document.getElementById("ul");
const input = document.getElementById("entrada");


const tarefas = [];




function validaEntrada() {
  console.log(input.value)
  if (input.value != "") {
    addTarefa();

  } else {
    alert("Digite uma Entrada!!!")
  }
}

function apresentarTarefa() {
  ul.innerHTML = ''

  for (texto of tarefas) {

    var novatarefa = document.createElement('li');
    novatarefa.appendChild(document.createTextNode(texto));
    console.log(novatarefa)

    ul.appendChild(novatarefa);

    const deleteBtn = document.createElement('button')
    const pos = tarefas.indexOf(texto)
    console.log(pos)

    deleteBtn.setAttribute('onclick', `removeTarefa(${pos})`);

    deleteBtn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("X"));
    novatarefa.appendChild(deleteBtn);

  }

  function risco() {
    novatarefa.classList.toggle("feito")
  }
 
  novatarefa.addEventListener("click", risco);



}

apresentarTarefa()

function addTarefa() {

  var tarefa = input.value;

  tarefas.push(tarefa);

  input.value = ''
  apresentarTarefa()


}

function removeTarefa(pos) {
  tarefas.splice(pos, 1)
  apresentarTarefa()


}
```

```css
#ul {
  border: 2px solid black;
  list-style-type: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  width: 50vw;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  gap: 15px;
}

.feito {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.cabecalho {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.entrada-dados {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

#entrada {
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


  <title>Lista</title>
</head>



<body>
  <header class="cabecalho">
    <h1>Tarefa</h1>
  </header>
  <article>
    <nav class="entrada-dados">
      <input id="entrada" type="text" placeholder="Digite nova Tarefa">
      <button id="btn" onclick="validaEntrada()">enviar</button>

    </nav>
    <aside>
      <ul id="ul" class="lista">

      </ul>
    </aside>

</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Pelo texto da pergunta não dá para entender o que quer fazer e o que precisa. Mas analisando o código parece que você tem que remover a linha `novatarefa.addEventListener("click", risco);` e a colocar embaixo da linha `novatarefa.appendChild(deleteBtn);`: Seu código vai ficar assim: https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/line-through#index.html

Comment: e difícil explicar tipo digita 3 entrada e clica em cima de umas da entradas eu queria que o nome da entrada que clicasse ficasse riscado mas não acontece isso risca sempre o ultima entrada

Comment: Eu sei que é difícil explicar, mas edite a pergunta e de uma esclarecida, com o ultimo comentário eu já entendi o problema. Na pergunta pode ser colocado as imagens do problema acontecendo ou gif mostrando o problema. Leia com calma o [Checklist de perguntas do Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8496/137387) que vai o ajudar a reformular a  pergunta. Depois do almoço eu dou uma passada aqui, talvez(sem compromissos) deixo uma resposta.

Answer (score 1):

A forma que você esta criando a lista das tarefas é onde esta quebrando o seu código.

Você não precisa criar um array de tarefas para fazer o controle do que vai ser removido porque como você esta criando o botão delete dentro do li, você consegue através deste botão acessar o li e aplicar o estilo de line-through utilizando o EventListner `click` em seu botão.

E trabalhando com o EventListner você não precisa utilizar o `onclick="validaEntrada()"` que esta no seu html.

```
const ul = document.getElementById('list');
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const input = document.getElementById('entrada');

function apresentarTarefa(tarefa) {
  const novatarefa = document.createElement('li');
  const deleteBtn = document.createElement('button');
  novatarefa.innerText = tarefa;
  deleteBtn.innerText = 'X';
  novatarefa.appendChild(deleteBtn);
  deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', (event) => removeTarefa(event));
  ul.appendChild(novatarefa);
}

function addTarefa() {
  // A validação que estava no html com o onclick é adicionada nesse momento.
  input.value ? apresentarTarefa(input.value) : alert('Digite uma Entrada!!!');

  input.value = '';
}

function removeTarefa(event) {
  // O event.target vai capturar o elemnt do btn e o parentNode vai trazer o li que é o item da lista uqe vai ser removido. Por final nele é aplicado o estilo de line-through

  event.target.parentNode.style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
}

// Ao trablhar com arrow function impete que a função addTarefa() seja executada quando o arquivo carregar
btn.addEventListener('click', () => addTarefa());
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-9pzgmn?file=script.js